# Check Social Media Urls Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, url

so i want to check if a URL is YOUTUBE, INSTAGRAM, FACEBOOK or TIKTOK url in flutter in order to display it correctly in the chat, so is there a regex or a method to do that ?

this is what i try to do, i didn't know if it cover all types of URL

```
  static bool isYouTubeUrl(String url) {
    return RegExp(
      r'^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
    ).hasMatch(url);
  }

  static bool isFacebookUrl(String url) {
    Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
    return uri != null &&
        (uri.host == 'www.facebook.com' || uri.host == 'facebook.com');
  }

  static bool isInstagramUrl(String url) {
    Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
    return uri != null &&
        (uri.host == 'www.instagram.com' || uri.host == 'instagram.com');
  }

  static bool isTikTokUrl(String url) {
    Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
    return uri != null &&
        (uri.host == 'www.titok.com' || uri.host == 'titok.com');
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest to open manifest file of these apps and look for intent-filters for patterns.

Comment: @Rahul i didn't understand explain more to me please

Comment: Each android app has manifest file where developer registers their different uri for deep link. If you look at it, you will find all the urls which the app supports.

Comment: @Rahul what do you mean by the (urls which the app supports), i didn't find such thing inside the manifest file, what i want to do is just how i can check if a url is a youtube url or instagram url... in the flutter app